# How do Javascript Reassigning and Reference works in case of Object ? In depth explanation required?

Tags: javascript, object, reference, javascript-objects

It seems to be a very common thing but a bit confusing. I am stuck at 2 scenarios and trying to understand what is happening over here.

**Scenario 1**

```js
let obj2 = {b:{c:{d:4}}}
let obj1 = {a:obj2['b']}

obj2['b'] =9

console.log(obj1)// --- > { a: { c: { d: 4 } } }
console.log(obj2)// --- > { b: 9 }
```

When I changed the value of `obj2['b']` I was expecting obj1 will also change as `obj1['a']` was
also referencing the same memory location but it didn't.

**Scenario 2**

```js
let obj2 = {b:{c:{d:4}}}
let obj1 = {a:obj2['b']}

obj2['b']['c'] =9

console.log(obj1)// --- > { a: { c: 9 } }
console.log(obj2)// --- > { b: { c: 9 } }
```

When I changed the value of `obj2['b']['c']` value of `obj1['a']['c']` also changes because it was
referencing to the same memory location. That I understood, it is expected behavior.

I want an explanation of Scenario 1, why it didn't change the value of obj1 ?

Comment: OK, do you understand why `a = {foo: 1}; b = a; a = {bar: 2}` doesn't change `b` while `a = {foo: 1}; b = a; a.foo = 2` does? Because you've created the exact same scenario but made it more confusing using objects.

Comment: In the first example, references are not being shared.  Values are being shared.  So when you change what value `obj2.b` references after `obj2.a` is set to reference the previous value, the change to what `obj2.b` references is independent of the other object.

Comment: @VLAZ Can you explain this a bit, a = {foo: 1}; b = a; a = {bar: 2}.  By this logic of your why does in Scenario 2 obj2['b']['c'] changed the value of obj1 ?

Comment: @SiddharthaNarang the code you quoted corresponds to scenario 1, not to scenario 2.

Comment: @VLAZ I know that example is for Scenario 1. Can you explain that bit more.

Comment: @SiddharthaNarang *assigning* a new object doesn't modify the any other assignments to the same object. It just changes the variable `a` to point at a new place, while `b` still point to the original object. With `a.foo = 2` both `a` and `b` point to the same object and the code is doing a modification to said object. If you have two pieces of paper with my name written on it on each, that's akin to `b = a`. Both notes refer to only me. Changing one of the pieces of paper doesn't replace me, nor does it affect what the other piece of paper says (Scenario 1).

Answer (score 2):

I think some diagrams might be useful here to help show what's going on. In your first code block, after your first two lines of code execute, you have a situation which looks like this:

[image: reference diagram both objects sharing the same reference]

Notice that both keys `b` and `a` from both objects 1 & 2 store references to the same object in memory. Once line three executes, you get the following situation:

[image: reference diagram once value 9 has been set]

As you can see, the `b` key for `obj2` now holds the value `9`, and no longer holds a reference to the object. However, obj1 *still* holds a reference to the object. As a result, when you log `obj1`, you'll still see the `c` and `d` properties of the nested objects.

---

For scenario two, however, your situation is a little different. After the first two lines of code execute, you get the same diagram as shown in the first image of this answer. However, once line 3 executes, your diagram changes to be:

[image: reference diagram once value 9 has been set]

In this situation the keys `a` and `b` for objects 1 and 2 *still* store references to the same object in memory (unlike in the previous scenario). This time, the object they both point to in memory is updated so that the value at the `c` key is no longer a reference to an object in memory, but rather the *value* `9`. As a result, when you log both obj1 and obj2, you see the *same* nested object.

The above diagrams were generated by [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) under the ES6 visualizer.

Answer (score 0):

In Scenario 1 you created an object (obj2) that has a property b that was assigned a reference to a new object, then you created a new object (obj1) and it has a property a that is a reference to the same object that in the b property in obj2.
once you changed the b property in obj2 the object that was in there is referenced only in obj1's a property.
basically, objects are in the heap memory and you store their addresses in the properties so once you change the property to a different thing you are not deleting it you just stop referencing the object and if nothing else is referencing it the GC will delete it eventually.